# Unexpected float behaviour in iPhone programming?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am writing just these four lines in ViewDidLoad, and facing unexpected output,

```
    // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


         float a = 15.264;
    NSLog(@"FLoat is %f",a);

        float b = 10/60;
    NSLog(@"FLoat is %f",b);
   }
```

In first float a is displaying correct value which is being assigned to a, but b is displaying 0.0000, why?

Comment: 10 is integer, 60 is integer, so 10/60 is 0. Try this: 10.0 / 60.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

float b = 10.0/60.0,

bcox, just 10/60 return int

Answer (score 3):

If you want to declare float numbers, you should declare them with this format: `x.xf`. E.g `float b = 10.0f/60.0f`

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the result of an integer division to a float, meaning, the result will be truncated before being assigned. In other words, `10/60`, which would be `0.1666...` yields the result `0`, which is then assigned to `b`. So, `b` has the value zero.

Answer (score 2):

Since both operands are integer, the result of your division is an integer (0). If you want the float result of your division you should use

```
float b = 10.0/60.0
```

or even

```
float b = 10.0/60
```

because you need at least one of the operands to be float.